# Activating a virtual environnement inside a .bat stops it from executing next commands

Tags: python, batch-file

My .bat file looks like this:

```
cd somewhere
virtualenv/Scripts/activate
cd somewhere_else
set FLASK_APP=flask_app.py
python -m flask
flask run
```

However the .bat stops after the second line (`virtualenv/Scripts/activate`).

How can I make it keep executing the following lines ?

Comment: I suspect `activate` is a batch file itself (with `,bat` or `,cnd` extension). If yes, you need to `call` it.

Comment: it does get called though, it just gets stuck **after** the call of activate (I can see the (myvirtualenv) that appears)

Comment: It does get *executed*, not *called*. Use `call virtualenv/Scripts/activate`

Comment: Oh wow you were right. Thank you so much. Not sure I get the difference though, could you elaborate on the difference between calling and executing another batch file? .bat files are always a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: Regular execution goes to the other script and stays there, `call` tells the execution flow to return to the main file once the other script completes.

Comment: `Execute a batch file`: "go process that script and don't bother me any more". `Call a batch file`: "go process that script and then come back for new orders" (`!`: `Execute an application`: "start that application and come back for new orders. The app will tell you to return immediately or to wait until it's finished". (Command line apps will usually finish before allowing return, GUI apps will usually cause immediate return). Batch seems fuzzy to you because it **is** fuzzy)

Comment: I had similar issue when running activate.bat. It terminated when reading long PATH variable in batch. Not sure if it is shell environment memory overflow or if content is somehow parsed. I had to manually remove saving old PATH variable to get it working.